A woman comes out of a mirror and kills a man in jail
I think this was at the end of the movie. A woman is seen running from a man in the woods. Above them is a helicopter. The woman runs until she sees a body of water. She jumps in and sees a little girl in the water with her. They both smile. The next scene shows a man in jail. There is a mirror in his cell. A woman comes out of the mirror and kisses the man, before biting his tongue hard. She then kills him by knocking his head against the mirror.

Second part looks a bit like Mirror 2. Can you explain it a bit more.

In Dreams (1999)

"Finally, the film is quickly put to rest through a weak helicopter
  chase that ends in tragedy."
"But nobody believes her being able to foresee the killer's next
  steps, as she could with her own daughter. In addition, the nervous
  breakdown she suffers gets her into a mental facility after a suicide
  attempt. And here, locked away in a padded cell, she dreams of her
  husband being murdered."

There's a lot of talk of water and apples in the rest of the 140+ reviews.
Here's the ending, at 1:30 you see the kiss and at at 2:36 you see him getting his head knocked against a door window and he dies.

i remember seeing that movie long time ago, don't remember that scene OP asks
